# Telerik RadGrid using Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

I am having a problem with the RadGrid using Multiple Columns when I Bind a DataSource to the RadGrid. Firstly let me show some screenshots of what I am trying to do.

This is an example from Teleriks website under demos and the multiple columns (summary column) is what I am trying to achieve 
[image: RadGrid Example from Telerik/demo]

This is the exception I am getting when I try and bind the control to a DataSource

[image: RagGridException]

This is the RadGrid I have set up in my ASP page.

[image: RaGrid Asp]

Firstly I don't want to bind the datasource in my asp page. Secondly I wanted the "Product" and "Other" ColumnGroups to be used only as a Summary column and not to be bound to a datasource since these ColumnGroups are only used as headers for the other Columns.

Is there a workaround to not allow the ColumnGroups not to be bound to a DataSource while the normal columns are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, each one of your columns is specifying a ColumnGroupName that does not exist. Your two groups are called OtherDetails and ProductDetails not Product and Other. Change them to resolve the exception.

Secondly, the GridColumGroups are simply groups, as they are not bound to any data from your datasource; they are simply for aesthetics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, stupid of me to think there was a problem with databinding.